# Another Populate Dropdownlist from another Dropdownlist selected value using stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, drop-down-menu

I have found several solutions online for similar topic but I have not found any clear solution and explanations for the case I am dealing with. Here are the questions/areas I needed helps with:

1. How to populate the second Dropdownlist (EmailDDL) with the Contact Information (Email) based on the selected Company in the first Dropdownlist (CompanyDDL). Two things I wanted to pointed out here are:
   a. I have only ONE table Not two and I have no associate IDs as mentioned in other solution. (see below)
   b. I am using Stored Procedure in my code behind (see below)
2. I am not so clear on the differences between  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ContactEmailList_SelectedIndexChanged" and how my sproc2 storedprocedure filters the email list by using @Company value. Would some one share the knowledges? In another word, how the selected value in the first dropdownlist passed to the stored procedure sproc2?
3. I have no problem populate the first dropdownlist using just the dropdownlist asp control  without having to use Dataset or SqlDataAdapter . Would I need to use those for the second dropdownlist?
4. So far I get the 1st dropdown (Companies list) and a long list of all emails in the second dropdownlist (ContactEmail). I need to have the second list filtered by the first one. Please helps. If it is possible a step by step approach with illustrated  code sample would be very heplful and appreciated.

   Thanks

Background Info:

2 stored procedures: sproc1 and sproc2 and 1 SQL table ( ContactInfo) with 3 columns:

Company, ContactName, ContactEmail.

```
sproc1: procedure [dbo].[sproc1]
    as
    begin
    Select distinct [Company] From [ContactInfo]
    end
sproc2:  procedure [dbo].[sproc2] @Company nvarchar(50) = null
    as
    begin
    Select distinct [ContactName],[ContactEmail] From [ContactInfo]
           where [Company] = @Company
    end

aspx:
//First Dropdownlist:

<p>Company:<br /> 
<asp:DropDownList ID="Company_DDList" runat="server"  
              Width="355px" Height="24px" 
              DataSourceID="ContactInfo"  
              DataTextField="Company"  
              DataValueField="Company" 
              AutoPostBack="true"  
              AppendDataBoundItems="true"
              onselectedindexchanged = 
              "Company_DDList_SelectedIndexChanged">                        
              <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" 
                   Selected="True" 
                   Text="-- select --">
              </asp:ListItem>   
</asp:DropDownList>     
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ContactInfo" runat="server"  
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:My_ConnectionString %>"  
 SelectCommand="sproc1"  
 SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>

//Second Dropdownlist:

<p>Contact:<br /> 
<asp:DropDownList ID="Contact_DDList" runat="server"  
              Width="355px" Height="24px" 
              DataSourceID="ContactInfo"  
              DataTextField="Email"  
              DataValueField="Email" 
              AutoPostBack="true"  
              AppendDataBoundItems="true"
              onselectedindexchanged="Contact_DDList_SelectedIndexChanged">                  
              <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" 
                   Selected="True" 
                   Text="-- select --">
              </asp:ListItem>   
</asp:DropDownList>     
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ContactInfo" runat="server"  
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:My_ConnectionString %>"  
 SelectCommand="sproc2"  
 SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>

aspx.c  //////////////////////////////

using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
using System.Configuration; 
using System.Net.Mail; 
using System.Net; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{ 
public string query; 
SqlConnection con = new
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString); 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 if (!IsPostBack) 
    { 
    con.Open(); 
    //SubmitButton.Enabled = false; 
    //Label1.Visible = false;
    }
protected void Company_DDList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs            
e)
{
    query = "sproc2"; 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con); 
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    ?????
} 
protected void Contact_DDList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs 
e)               
{          
//
{
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call second dropdown change event after complete first dropdown

```
 protected void Company_DDList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,            EventArgs            
e)
 {
query = "sproc2"; 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con); 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Contact_DDList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
}
```

the below code call second dropdown change event after first dropdown chagnes. try it.

Comment: This is where I am not sure what to do for the 2nd dropdown. Since I was able to get my first dropdown as described above in my aspx, I did not have to do anything in aspx.cs. So nothing needed for Contact_DDList_SelectedIndexeChanged? Does onselectedindexedchanged take care of the passing selected item from the first dropdownlist? If not, do I need to pass the company in place of "sender"? Thanks

Comment: I tried what you told me and I go nowhere further than before. I did try with ContactEmail_DDList.DataTextfield = "Email"; ContactEmail_DDListDataValueField = "Email" ContactEmail_DDList.DataBind(); Can you share with me the steps (examples)? Thks